# Can motivic cohomology say anything about real points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two smooth schemes defined over $\mathbf Z$.
Suppose that we have a scheme morphism inducing isomorphisms on motivic cohomology groups $\mathrm H^p(Y,\mathbf Z(q)) \simeq \mathrm H^p(X,\mathbf Z(q))$ (maybe only for some values of $p$).

I think that, on the level of complex points, the induced map is also an isomorphism on singular cohomology groups :$\mathrm H^p(Y(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z) \simeq \mathrm H^p(X(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z)$.

My question is: do we have the same conclusion on the level of real points; that is do we have also induced isomorphisms  $\mathrm H^p(Y(\mathbf R),\mathbf Z) \simeq \mathrm H^p(X(\mathbf R),\mathbf Z)$?

I suspect this is not true; so a counterexample would be welcome (where $X$ and $Y$ may be more fancy objects than just brave schemes).
Also, what if we suppose more on $X$ and $Y$ (as: what if their motives $M(X), M(Y)$ are mixed Tate? for example)?

Comment: The answer is indeed no: as the reduced cohomology of $P^1$ shows.